# Umbrella term for typography, lettering, calligraphy

Tags: typography, font-design, typefaces, lettering, calligraphy

Is there a term to refer to the type design, lettering, calligraphy, and other related types of art/design?

Comment: Wouldn't Lettering and Calligraphy fall under Typography?

Comment: "type design" would as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word you're looking for is **typography**.

Typography encompasses everything you've listed - lettering, calligraphy, unique design of glyphs within a typeface, or merely how type is used in a layout/design.